# Change selected text color easily?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to develop dark mode and light mode for my website. I've done that, but now selected text looks weird in light mode. I want to change the selected text color of it using JavaScript. I've seen this code posted around, so I'm not sure if it helps. But I'll provide it anyway.

```css
<style>
::selection {
    color:blue;
    background:yellow;
    font-size:14px;
}

::-moz-selection {
    color:blue;
    background:yellow;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>
```

To reiterate, **I'm trying to set the selected text color css using JavaScript**. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What kind of light / dark mode do you use? Are there 2 different classes that show the dark & light mode?

Comment: Yes! The default css is dark mode. The html is modified to use light mode classes when the switch is made.

Comment: @ReeseEverett-S so is the dark/light classes applied on the body?

Comment: Yeah, not the most efficient but it works well.

Comment: Okay, here's what you could do: There is the possibility to use variables in CSS. For the class .dark, you write in the respective colour that the selected text should have. You do the same for the class .light for the light mode. (An example for a css variable: `--selectionColor: #FAFAFA;`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it!

Comment: @ReeseEverett-S I have added an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### CSS custom properties / CSS Variables will be a better approach.

You can do something like this:

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
const darkMode = document.getElementById("darkMode");

darkMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
  root.style.setProperty("--selectionBG", "blueviolet");
  root.style.setProperty("--selectionColor", "turquoise");

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#111";
  document.body.style.color = "#eee";
});
```

```css
:root {
  --selectionBG: cyan;
  --selectionColor: navy;
}

::selection {
  color: var(--selectionColor);
  background: var(--selectionBG);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="darkMode">Dark Mode</button>

  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet natus quia minus cum.</h1>
</body>
```

[Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/wvgGvJe)